# Rails how to translate captions on form inputs file_field ( i18n )

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, input, translation

I'm building translation for my application, but I cannot figure out how to translate the default captions for form fields.

Specifically the file_form tag.  The default is to produce a button with the caption 'Choose file' and a note to the side stating 'No file chosen'

Where in the yml do these translations exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, <input type="file"> and how it appears to the user is up to the browser, and it's not possible to chance all too much of it.

You can find several articles about styling them to look a bit different, but the text on the button itself and the note depends on the language of the browser the user are running, and you cannot change it (at least nothing I can find)

Answer (score 0):

you better use bootstrap file upload. The code below is for my application and its multilanguage

```
= transloadit :image_resize
-6.times do |index|
  .fileupload.fileupload-new.pull-left{style: "padding-right: 5px;", "data-provides" => "fileupload" }
    .fileupload-new.thumbnail{:style => "width: 130px; height: 130px;"} 
      -if @provider.provider_images.present?
        - if @provider.provider_images["provider_image#{index+1}"].present?
          %img{:id=>"providerimage1", :src => @provider.provider_images["provider_image#{index+1}"][0]}/
    .fileupload-preview.fileupload-exists.thumbnail{:style => "width: 130px; height: 130px;"}
    %div
      %span.btn.btn-file
        %span.fileupload-new{:id => "selectbutton"}
          -if index == 0
            =t('select_profile_image')  
          -else
            =t('select_image')              
        %span.fileupload-exists
          -if index == 0
            =t('select_profile_image')  
          -else
            =t('select_image')      
        =file_field_tag "provider_image#{index+1}"
```